# How do you auto refresh an HTML table every few seconds?

Tags: refresh

Is there a way to auto refresh an HTML table inside a DIV tag every few seconds without refreshing the whole page?

Comment: It's called [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) (Provided you mean you want to refresh it with something from the server-side ... otherwise, it's just plain JavaScript)

Comment: @Brian It's JS in both case, it's just that one of those cases involves XmlHttpRequest.

Comment: @Etienne - Touche. But you know what I meant ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one ways to achieve this. Easiest thing that comes to mind is have a Javascript timer run every few seconds to make an AJAX call to refresh the DIV tag enclosing the table.

Here is some info on Javascript timing functions

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can choose some javascript frameworks thats already use Ajax to do it.
For example Extjs libraty. In this library you will need to invoke method of the store